# Updating id elements in react Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I recently started with react (alongside react-native) and a lot of things are alien to me. I was creating an app in react native which shows cryptocurrency value in real time.

Coin cap provides web-socket connection so that the new values are automatically updated instead of fetching the entire stuff using axios.

Now, In simple HTML and javascript world, I assigned an ID to the elements and used `for loop` whenever the new data came from web-socket to find the value I need to update(or change).

Something like this

```
var socket = io.connect('https://coincap.io');
socket.on('trades', function (tradeMsg) {
  var crypto = tradeMsg.coin;
  for (let i=0; i<500; i++) {
    var compare = cryptoSName[i].innerHTML;
    if (compare == crypto) {
      var oldPrice = document.getElementById('price' + i).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('price' + i).innerHTML= (tradeMsg.message.msg.price.toFixed(4));;
      document.getElementById('perc' + i).innerHTML= tradeMsg.message.msg.perc + "%";
      document.getElementById('pricer1' + i).innerHTML= (tradeMsg.message.msg.price.toFixed(4));;
      document.getElementById('percr1' + i).innerHTML= tradeMsg.message.msg.perc + "%";
      var newPrice = tradeMsg.message.msg.price;
```

**[Question]** In react I can still assign an ID to the elements but how can we do something like that (using web-socket to update data)? Also, keeping in mind how react components render (or re-render) things.

**[Update]** I am using Redux which stores the data in a state. Consider this

Data/state I receive from redux (through axios api call in some action)

```
class cryptoTicker extends Component { 
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchCoin();
  }
  render() { 
    var CryptoData = this.props.cryptoLoaded;
    let displayCrypto = CryptoData.map(el => {
      return (
        <CoinCard
          key={el["long"]}
          coinPrice = {el["price"].toFixed(2)}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <ScrollView>{displayCrypto}</ScrollView>
    );
  }
} 
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cryptoLoaded: state.posts.itemsSucess
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchCoin})(cryptoTicker);
```

**Note**: Initially all the data is fetched through axios (ajayx) and websocket only sends changes in the fetched data

Just in case: Here is the link to coincap api's documentation
https://github.com/CoinCapDev/CoinCap.io

Comment: Should be thinking completely differently and not creating elements yourself. Should be updating stored data arrays and letting react create all the elements from them

Comment: Instead of manually manipulating the DOM, you should keep you values in the component state and use `setState` to update it when you get a socket message. This way the component will re-render automatically.

Comment: @charlietfl Updated my post.

Comment: @Tholle Updated my post